# Duplicate data of tree table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem like this : duplicate data in column 'City_' if table Customer has the customer lives in the same city . How I can fix it ! Thanks so much !

```
WITH OrderCategory(Country, City, OrderNumber, alevel)
AS(
SELECT DISTINCT Country,
City = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(255)),
OrderNumber = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(255)),
alevel = 0
FROM Customer C

UNION ALL

SELECT C.Country,
City = CAST(C.City AS NVARCHAR(255)),
OrderNumber = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(255)),
alevel = OC.alevel + 1
FROM OrderCategory OC
INNER JOIN Customer C ON OC.Country = C.Country 
WHERE OC.alevel = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT C.Country,
City = CAST(C.City AS NVARCHAR(255)),
OrderNumber = CAST(O.OrderNumber AS NVARCHAR(255)),
alevel = OC.alevel + 1
FROM OrderCategory OC
INNER JOIN (Customer C INNER JOIN [Order] O ON C.Id = O.CustomerId) ON 
OC.Country = C.Country AND OC.City = C.City
WHERE OC.alevel = 1
)
SELECT [Country_] = CASE WHEN alevel = 0 THEN Country ELSE '--' END,
   [City_] = CASE WHEN alevel = 1 THEN City ELSE '----' END,
   [OrderID] = OrderNumber,
   [Level] = alevel
FROM OrderCategory
ORDER BY Country , City ,OrderNumber, alevel
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeWNc.png)

Comment: Hi there, it is normal to paste the code used into the question, rather than linking the image. Could you edit your question by pasting in the code in code block format?

Comment: sorry , this is the first time I post question , I changed it ! I hope you can help me !

Answer (score 0):

in this situation, I think, you just use `Union` instead of `Union All`

Comment: It seems, should work with `Union` and `Distinct` after `Select`